# How to get row count of all tables available under 50schemas in TERADATA?

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

I cannot create procedure to get count as i do have only read access in TERADATA server.

Please suggest me a query to get rowcount of all tables available under 50 schemas FROM DBC.tablesV.

I don't find any data dictionaries as like Oracle to fetch rowcounts fr all_table.

Please help me!!

I found rowcount available under dbc.tablestatsv. but it's updated with as decimal and more are wrong value.

Answer (score 0):

The row count in DBC Stats views is a snapshot as of the last COLLECT STATISTICS so should be considered approximate at best. The only way to get an accurate count is to do SELECT COUNT(*) from each table. If you can't use a Stored Procedure the you will have to iterate through the list with some client side scripting. Fairly simple to do in Java, Python, etc. Or you can do it in two steps - generate a bunch of SELECT statements using the dictionary view, then run that generated SQL:

```
SELECT 'SELECT '''||DatabaseName||''','''||TableName||''',COUNT(*) FROM '||DatabaseName||'.'||TableName||';'
FROM DBC.TablesV WHERE DatabaseName IN (_list of names_);
```

Comment: You can also create a table to hold the results and generate INSERT/SELECT statements instead; then query that table to return a single result set.